# Coordinate System is `' (empty) in GeoTIFF when checking with GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff

Following is the output for my `gdalinfo mygeo.tif`.

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 3489_DUBLIN_AREA_2KM2_rgb_124639_id32c1_20150326115630.tif
Size is 9000, 6732
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=254
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=0
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=FramePro 1.3.0.2569 (rev 68105)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 6732.0)
Upper Right ( 9000.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 9000.0, 6732.0)
Center      ( 4500.0, 3366.0)
Band 1 Block=9000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=9000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=9000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

mygeo.tif is a georeferenced tiff (GeoTIFF) image. Therefore, I reckon it **should** display the coordinate reference system. What could be the possible reason to see it blank?

Comment: For Dublin (Ireland) you will need to use the Irish national grid https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/tm65-irish-grid/  > there is a qgis guide for Ireland here http://www.burrengeopark.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/A-Practical-Guide-to-Using-QGIS.pdf

Comment: The coordinate reference system does not need to be defined for a GeoTIFF, it can be undefined, but what you have there isn't a GeoTIFF, look at the coordinates, upper left is 0,0 that's an indication that this file is not georeferenced. Are you missing the associated PRJ, TFW and .TIF.AUX files?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your image is not true GeoTIFF or it is corrupted. You can check the GeoTIFF tags of the image with **listgeo** utility http://geotiff.maptools.org/listgeo.html or with **tiffinfo** tool http://www.libtiff.org/man/tiffinfo.1.html. Report from listgeo is easier to read while tiffinfo may suit better for serious debugging because it shows the exact tag numbers and field values. Windows users can get these command line utilities by installing [OSGeo4W](https://www.osgeo.org/projects/osgeo4w/).

Parts of the reports about a valid GeoTIFF:

```
listgeo test.tif
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered.
Geotiff_Information:
   Version: 1
   Key_Revision: 1.0
   Tagged_Information:
      ModelTiepointTag (2,3):
         0                 0                 0
         -11914525.1483331 4478208.11503727  0
      ModelPixelScaleTag (1,3):
         100               100               0
      End_Of_Tags.
   Keyed_Information:
      GTModelTypeGeoKey (Short,1): ModelTypeProjected
      GTRasterTypeGeoKey (Short,1): RasterPixelIsArea
      GTCitationGeoKey (Ascii,25): "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator"
      GeogCitationGeoKey (Ascii,7): "WGS 84"
      GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Angular_Degree
      ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey (Short,1): Unknown-3857
      ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Linear_Meter
      End_Of_Keys.
   End_Of_Geotiff.

tiffinfo test.tif
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered.
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 33 Image Length: 42
  Bits/Sample: 32
  Sample Format: IEEE floating point
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 42
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Tag 33550: 100.000000,100.000000,0.000000
  Tag 33922: 0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,-11914525.148333,4478208.115037,0.000000
  Tag 34735: 1,1,0,7,1024,0,1,1,1025,0,1,1,1026,34737,25,0,2049,34737,7,25,2054,0,1,9102,3072,0,1,3857,3076,0,1,9001
  Tag 34737: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator|WGS 84|
  Tag 42112: <GDALMetadata>
```

Comment: Can you include a link to the tool you're talking about? It sounds like a really handy tool to have, like GeoTIFF Examiner (I think http://www.mediafire.com/file/a3hv2q9bchez8u8/geotiffexaminer.exe/file is the right link, the original developer can't easily be found on the internet) and the ECW Header editor.